# QtWebKit 2.2 segfaults when loading specific website

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

The past months I have been putting together my own QtWebKit-based browser ([WildFox](http://www.mayaposch.com/wildfox.php), BSD-licensed) and it's been an overall quite pleasant experience. I have noticed odd crashes however, basically right from the beginning. Yesterday I decided to take a deeper look at these crashes when it failed to repeatedly load my personal website, www.mayaposch.com.

The sequence of events is as follows: I use `load()` or `setUrl()` to tell the `QWebView` element to load http://www.mayaposch.com, `loadFinished()` returns false, indicating something went wrong during loading of the page and then the application segmentation faults.

I'm using Qt 4.8 (latest SDK), both release and debug libraries (dynamic).

The stack trace while running the debug build with gdb:

```
0   WTF::HashTable<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, std::pair<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SubstituteResource> >, WTF::PairFirstExtractor<std::pair<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SubstituteResource> > >, WTF::PtrHash<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> >, WTF::PairHashTraits<WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> >, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SubstituteResource> > >, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> > >::isEmpty() const D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xbcd036e   
1   WTF::HashMap<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SubstituteResource>, WTF::PtrHash<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> >, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> >, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SubstituteResource> > >::isEmpty() const D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xbcc7315   
2   WebCore::DocumentLoader::cancelPendingSubstituteLoad(WebCore::ResourceLoader*)  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb3cbb96   
3   WebCore::ResourceLoader::didCancel(WebCore::ResourceError const&)   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb62277f   
4   WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didCancel(WebCore::ResourceError const&)    D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb75859c   
5   WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel(WebCore::ResourceError const&)  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb622900   
6   WebCore::ResourceLoader::cancel()   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb62285a   
7   WebCore::cancelAll(WTF::HashSet<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader>, WTF::PtrHash<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> >, WTF::HashTraits<WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::ResourceLoader> > > const&) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb3c8725   
8   WebCore::DocumentLoader::stopLoadingSubresources()  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb3cbfa4   
9   WebCore::DocumentLoader::stopLoading()  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb3ca9e0   
10  WebCore::FrameLoader::stopAllLoaders(WebCore::ClearProvisionalItemPolicy)   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f3694   
11  WebCore::FrameLoader::continueLoadAfterNavigationPolicy(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, bool) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f7d29   
12  WebCore::FrameLoader::callContinueLoadAfterNavigationPolicy(void*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, bool)  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f76a1   
13  WebCore::PolicyCallback::call(bool) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb56e06c   
14  WebCore::PolicyChecker::continueAfterNavigationPolicy(WebCore::PolicyAction)    D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb56ed26   
15  WebCore::FrameLoaderClientQt::callPolicyFunction(void (WebCore::PolicyChecker::*)(WebCore::PolicyAction), WebCore::PolicyAction)    D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb141188   
16  WebCore::FrameLoaderClientQt::dispatchDecidePolicyForNavigationAction(void (WebCore::PolicyChecker::*)(WebCore::PolicyAction), WebCore::NavigationAction const&, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>)  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb146959   
17  WebCore::PolicyChecker::checkNavigationPolicy(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, void (*)(void*, WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, bool), void*)   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb56e7ef   
18  WebCore::FrameLoader::loadWithDocumentLoader(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f25e9   
19  WebCore::FrameLoader::loadWithNavigationAction(WebCore::ResourceRequest const&, WebCore::NavigationAction const&, bool, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>)    D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f1fc5   
20  WebCore::FrameLoader::loadURL(WebCore::KURL const&, WTF::String const&, WTF::String const&, bool, WebCore::FrameLoadType, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f17f1   
21  WebCore::FrameLoader::loadFrameRequest(WebCore::FrameLoadRequest const&, bool, bool, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::FormState>, WebCore::ReferrerPolicy) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2f1086   
22  WebCore::FrameLoader::urlSelected(WebCore::FrameLoadRequest const&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, bool, bool, WebCore::ReferrerPolicy, WebCore::ShouldReplaceDocumentIfJavaScriptURL)    D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2ece3e   
23  WebCore::FrameLoader::changeLocation(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::SecurityOrigin>, WebCore::KURL const&, WTF::String const&, bool, bool, bool)  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb2ec9de   
24  WebCore::ScheduledURLNavigation::fire(WebCore::Frame*)  D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xbc30de8   
25  WebCore::NavigationScheduler::timerFired(WebCore::Timer<WebCore::NavigationScheduler>*) D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb3cd565   
26  WebCore::Timer<WebCore::NavigationScheduler>::fired()   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xbc7adb2   
27  WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal()   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb4a84e6   
28  WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFired()   D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb4a8433   
29  WebCore::SharedTimerQt::timerEvent(QTimerEvent*)    D:\Dev\Qt\SDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.0\mingw\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll 0   0xb686a5a   
30  QObject::event  qobject.cpp 1157    0x6a22499a  
31  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    4550    0xa4c020    
32  QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3932    0xa49973    
33  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    876 0x6a213252  
34  QCoreApplication::sendEvent qcoreapplication.h  231 0x6a283f54  
35  QEventDispatcherWin32::event    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    1135    0x6a23ac60  
36  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    4550    0xa4c020    
37  QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3932    0xa49973    
38  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    876 0x6a213252  
39  QCoreApplication::sendEvent qcoreapplication.h  231 0x6a283f54  
40  QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents   qcoreapplication.cpp    1500    0x6a21416d  
41  qt_internal_proc    qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    496 0x6a238a2f  
42  USER32!IsDialogMessageW C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll  0   0x75a46238  
43  operator+       0   0x7113ae    
44  USER32!AllowForegroundActivation    C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll  0   0x75a468ea  
45  qt_fast_timer_proc  qeventdispatcher_win.cpp    428 0x6a2387c8  
46  USER32!GetMessageExtraInfo  C:\Windows\syswow64\user32.dll  0   0x75a47d31  
47  ??      0
```

The fault line (disassembly) is indicated as:

```
0xbcd036e  <+0x0006>         mov    0xc(%eax),%eax
```

Is this an internal `QtWebKit` fault? From the stack trace I'd say it is, but I lack the knowledge of its internals to say what is going wrong. The crashes happen most often on my personal site, but others have reported it crashing on other sites as well, including when interrupting loading (e.g. clicking a link before loading finished).

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion on #Qt @ Freenode IRC with Net147 (Jonathan Liu) it was determined that it was indeed due to a bug in webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83565

> The crash is caused by a null pointer dereference in Source/WebCore/loader/ResourceLoader.cpp in the function ResourceLoader::didCancel().
>   m_documentLoader->cancelPendingSubstituteLoad(this) is called without checking if m_documentLoader is null.

What I find most interesting is that my code triggered this bug while the Qt browser demo didn't. Anyone willing to figure out why this is the case is more than welcome to :)